# CPU freq always min when plugged in

Tags: power-management, cpufreq

I have a lenovo g510 with intel i7-4700 inside and after several months something strange has happend. When it runs using battery power everything is ok - cpu freq is scaling. But when it's plugged in then cpu feq is always about 800MHz.

```
lscpu
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
Wersja:                3
CPU MHz:               800.156
CPU max MHz:           3400,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              4789.02


cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver 
intel_pstate

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
powersave
```

I have also Windows on this laptop and situation is the same on both OS. I'm not using original charger but with the same parameter as original one.

Comment: On my Dell 17R 7720 SE laptop when plugged in it scales 1200 MHz to 3400 MHz. When on battery it is fixed at 1200 MHz to extend battery life. Your power management package (there are several to choose from) is working in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling `intel_pstate` through Linux kernel options as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591594/enable-full-performance-on-sandy-bridge-laptop).